# Laravel, how can I let the {{$i}} work when this value in the nest {{}}

Tags: laravel, for-loop

the index value $i in the nest {{}} can't work, have any solutions can let the index value work ?

```
@for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++)
    <label class="text-center mb-5 image-preview-wrapper" for="file-uploader">
        <img src="/{{Session::get('template_array_4.img{{$i}}')}}" alt="image-placehoder" class="img-thumbnail" data-target="image-preview">
    </label>
@endfor
```

Comment: Try `Session::get("template_array_4.img$i")`

Comment: no errors, but still not get the index value

Comment: Does for loop works?

Comment: yes, loop  can works

Comment: Session::get("template_array_4.img".$i), I try to add a dot and this can work, thanks for your help

Comment: If that works, my first approach should work, but anyways, if that helped, that's ok.